# How to draw a line on image using appcelerator titanium mobile

Tags: image, titanium, draw, pixel, touchmove

I'm want to make an application for Galaxy Tab, that allows me to draw pictures... Something similar to MS Paint (don't ask  my why :)) so the first steps are:

```
win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    exitOnClose: true
});

image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});

image.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
   //And here I need somehow to draw a pixel on image at e.x, e.y coordinates
   // How can i do it?
});
```

So, how should i draw a pixel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry I have not read you full Question.

try [This](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/807?373558631), this is a Titanium Appcelerator Module and this is absoultely free
It have also a easy example. You can use easy.

Again Really Sorry..

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly are you drawing a pixel on your imageView? I think that this example can used as Drag-and-Drop example, my question was about how to Draw a Pixel on my image view when i'm touching it... But thank you anyway.